# PHP PHAR: Once again about creation of .phar in a proper way

Tags: php, phar

I'm trying to create a PHAR Archive with executable stub. The code:

```
<?php
$phar = new Phar('test.phar');
$phar->buildFromDirectory('files/');
$phar->setStub($phar->createDefaultStub(file_get_contents('st.php'), 'install.php'));
?>
```

The contents of "st.php" (the default stub):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php Phar::mapPhar(); include("phar://test.phar/install.php"); __HALT_COMPILER();
```

Inside the "files" is only one file - the "install.php"

```
<?php
echo "The Installer is running right now.";
?>
```

PHAR compilation process runs with no any errors. But when I try to include the created PHAR archive

```
include_once('phar://test.phar');
```

the error occurs:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''#!/usr/bin/php\r' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in D:/WebServer/domains/modinst/www/test.phar on line 110
```

The question is: how to create a PHAR archive for use as a PHP resource that I can simply 'include'?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the shebang line within the stub file. This is a limitation of current PHP versions.

Remove it and the error will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

To set the shebang, use:

```
$phar->setStub("#!/usr/bin/env php" . PHP_EOL 
    . $phar->createDefaultStub(file_get_contents('st.php')));
```